# Why won't this for loop work for iterating through unix time?

Tags: php, time

I am trying to populate a select list with time.

I want to create the select list so that it starts from the starting date and then ends six months later.

I've created this for loop for now but it doesn't work:
    $dateSelectList = '';
    $startDate = $c->getStartDate(92);

```
$endDate = intval( strtotime('+6 month', $startdate) );
$i = 1;

$tempDate = 0;
for($date = $startdate; $date <= $endDate ; $date = strtotime('+1 day', $date))
{
    $dateSelectList .= '<option id="select'.$i.'" value="'.$date.'">'.$date.'</option>';
    $i++;
}
$dateSelectList .= '</select>';
```

I think it's the last field in the for loop but I don't know how to get around it.

I've changed it to  `$date = strtotime('+1 day', $date)` and it works now.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: You can't compare two dates like this: $date <= $endDate, because they are strings.

Comment: @AlexAmiryan ... if you'll notice, he's using `strtotime` which returns an int ... therefore, he can do direct comparisons ...

Comment: No, they're not -- they're unix timestamps.

Comment: @AlexHowansky ... Unix timestamp is an int ... http://it.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php ... `strtotime` returns an int ...

Comment: @dleiftah Yes sorry, I did not quality my reply -- it was to Alex, not you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each iteration, you're resetting the date to the start date plus one day. I.e., you're just using the same date over and over each iteration:

```
for($date = $startdate; $date <= $endDate ; $date = strtotime('+1 day', $startdate))
```

Change your for loop so that it keeps adding on to $date instead:

```
for($date = $startdate; $date <= $endDate ; $date = strtotime('+1 day', $date))
```

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of solutions. One of them may be:

### Code

```
$startdate = time(); // today;
$enddate = strtotime('+6 months', $startdate);

while ($startdate <= $enddate) {
  echo date('Y-m-d', $startdate) . "<br/>";
  $startdate = strtotime('+1 day', $startdate);
  }
```

### Output

```
2012-03-26
2012-03-27
2012-03-28
2012-03-29
2012-03-30
2012-03-31
2012-04-01
...
2012-09-24
2012-09-25
2012-09-26
```

Now, modify code and create your selector as you like.

Change first line to

```
$year = 2012;
$month = 3;
$day = 26;

$startdate = strtotime("$year-$month-$day 00:00:00 UTC");
```

and create your custom **$startdate**.

### Complete selector code

```
$year = 2012;
$month = 2;
$day = 3;

$startdate = strtotime("$year-$month-$day 00:00:00 UTC");
$enddate = strtotime('+6 months', $startdate);

$doc = "<select>"; $i=1;
while ($startdate <= $enddate) {
  $dt = date('Y-m-d', $startdate);
  $doc .= "<option id=\"select$i\" value=\"$dt\">$dt</option>";
  $startdate = strtotime('+1 day', $startdate);
  $i++;
  }
$doc .= "</select>";

echo $doc;
```

### Output

[image]

More elegant solution is to put it all into function like this

```
function createSelector($day, $month, $year) {
  $startdate = strtotime("$year-$month-$day 00:00:00 UTC");
  $enddate = strtotime('+6 months', $startdate);
  $doc = "<select>"; $i=1;
    while ($startdate <= $enddate) {
    $dt = date('Y-m-d', $startdate);
    $doc .= "<option id=\"select$i\" value=\"$dt\">$dt</option>";
    $startdate = strtotime('+1 day', $startdate);
    $i++;
    }
  $doc .= "</select>";
  return $doc;
  }
```

and call it this way

```
$selectorCode = createSelector(26, 3, 2012);
echo $selectorCode;
```

Cheers!

Comment: Wow, very nice! Thanks for your time :P

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, indeed, with this bit of code: `$date = strtotime('+1 day', $startdate)` ...

`$startdate` is never being changed, therefore, `$date` is never being changed. You'll want something more like `$date = strtotime('+1 day', $date)` in order for the loop to work properly.